# Is a hashing algorithm considered broken if a collision happens under $2^{n/2}$?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

If for example we would find a hash collision for SHA256 with $h(x) = h(x')$ for $x \ne x'$ and $x, \space x' < 128$ bit (meaning both $x$ and $x'$ are smaller than 128 bit), would SHA256 be considered broken?

Is it then *always* possible to create more collisions in a feasible time or could this hash collision just be considered an "anomaly"?

Comment: I think you mean $x,x' < 128$-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If for example we would find a hash collision for SHA256 with $h(x) = h(x')$ …

Yes, pretty much.  Now, I'm not certain what you meant by "$x \land x' < 128$ bit" (total bit length is less than 128 bits, or they disagree in at most 128 bits???), however, it doesn't really matter; finding any collision would demonstrate that SHA256 isn't quite as collision resistant as we had thought.

> Is it then always possible to create more collisions in feasible time or could this hash collision just be considered an "anomaly"?

If $x, x'$ had the same length (or, more generally, used the same number of SHA-256 blocks when hashing), then it's easy to find more collisions; we would have $h(x || Pad_x || y) = h(x' || Pad_{x'} || y)$ for any string $y$ (where $Pad_x, Pad_{x'}$ is the padding that SHA-256 applies when hashing $x, x'$).